# Was Hawaii the only state that never voted significantly more Republican than the national average?

Tags: united-states, voting, hawaii

I have read something (I don't remember where) that said: *Hawaii is the only state that never voted significantly more Republican than the nation as a whole. Its Democratic lean was more established during and after the 1980s.*

I know that it voted for Reagan and Nixon in their second election bids. Is this accurate?

Comment: I think you know the correct way to self-answer questions on this site.

Comment: If I'm not misunderstanding the Q., it seems logically equivalent to the easier to read *"Is Hawaii the only state that has always voted more Democrat than the national average?"*  If so, please clarify why the Q. is phrased as a negative.

Comment: @agc: Your proposed phrasing has a different answer: No, because as the answer notes, there have been two times when it was *not* more Democratic than the national average.

Comment: @Kevin, While the negative and positive forms of a Q. should have contrary answers, *e.g.*  Q: *"Is it raining?"* - A: *"Yes."*; Q: _"Is it_ not *raining?"* - A: *"No."*; the difference is logically **null**.

Comment: @agc: Let me try again. Your proposed wording removes the word "significantly," which is doing all of the heavy lifting in the current answer to the question. So your proposed wording has a different answer.

Comment: @Kevin, IOW:  Q: *"Is it raining buckets?"* - A: *"Yes."*; Q: *"Is it* not *raining?"* - A: *"No."*, versus Q: *"Is it* not *raining buckets?"* - A: *"No."* -- the former implies no rain at all, but the latter allows for mild rain *or* no rain.  Maybe...  but it's not obvious that the word  "significantly" is as meaningful to the OP as you impute.  Which is why this question needs focus...

Comment: @agc: The OP wrote the answer which hinges on "significant." So of course they care about that word, otherwise they would have written a different answer or no answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It depends on whether a gap of <1 percentage points in vote share is "significant". By two-party vote share (not margin):

1960: 0.1 percentage points more Republican than nation

1972: 0.7 percentage points more Republican than nation

**No other state shares such a distinction, unless you count DC as a state.**